# Smarty general block code inheritance

Tags: html, templates, inheritance, smarty, block

Is it real to get block content from parent file to child?
For example, I have 3 files `parent.tpl` & `first-child.tpl` & `second-child.tpl`

Parent contains that code:

```
<div>
    {block name='greetings'}{/block}
</div>
```

First-Child contains:

```
{extends file="parent.tpl"}
{block name='greetings'}
    <h1>Hello! I'm child</h1>
{/block}
```

Second-Child contains same as first greetings block (same text only), but instead of `h1` tag, second-child use `h4` tag:

```
{extends file="parent.tpl"}
{block name='greetings'}
    <h4>Hello! I'm child</h4>
{/block}
```

I don't want to duplicate that text `Hello! I'm child` in each child, but put this into own block. 
It can be done that way: Create new file `greeting_text.tpl` and include them into each child, but I don't want to allocate for that own file. I tried to declare that text into `parent.tpl`:

```
...
{block name='greetings_text'}Hello! I'm child{/block}
```

And get that from children:

```
{extends file="parent.tpl"}
{block name='greetings'}
    <h1>{block name='greetings_text'}{/block}</h1>
{/block}
```

and second-child:

```
{extends file="parent.tpl"}
{block name='greetings'}
    <h4>{block name='greetings_text'}{/block}</h4>
{/block}
```

But I understood it's impossible to take `block` content from parent to child. Or maybe i'm wrong. 
Please give me advice, how I can do that except put `greeting_text` into their own file and include them in children? Thanks!

---

**EDITED:**

Sorry, previous question text was a little bit incorrect (not fully describe what I'm trying to do)

How wrote **sofl**, it's work with `append` construction. But problem is, that i have 3 files, and two of them extendable (layout.tpl, default.tpl and page.tpl)

**layout.tpl**

```
<div class="layout">
  {block name="content"}{/block}
</div>
```

**default.tpl**

```
{extends file="layout.tpl"}

{block name='menu'}
  <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
  </ul>
{/block}
```

**page.tpl**

```
{extends file="default.tpl"}

{block name="content"}
  <div class="first-page-example">
      {block name='menu' append}{/block}

      <span>I'm text only for first page....</span>
  </div>
{/block}
```

I launch `page.tpl` (`$smarty->display('page.tpl')`), and i wanted to get `menu` from `default.tpl` to each child (`page.tpl`, p.s. there can be many child page1.tpl, page2.tpl,... But for all of them, needed to put default menu from `default.tpl`) And put that all to `layout.tpl` like a `content`. So how i can do that with `block` construction? Please, any advices.

Comment: Please help me guys. I know there are many skilled Smarty, guys who know why that contruction dont work. Give me advice how it's better to do, pleasee... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prepend` or `append` to keep the content of the parent block. http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.block.tpl

parent

```
<div>
    {block name='greetings'}<h4>Hello! I'm child</h4>{/block}
</div>
```

child

```
{extends file="parent.tpl"}
{block name='greetings' append}
    <h5>...here I am</h5>
{/block}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

It seems abit tricky. You might use more than one block `content`. The block `menu` in `default.tpl` has no placement.

Some possibilities

**layout.tpl**

```
<div class='layout'>
  {block name='content'}{/block}
</div>
```

**default.tpl**

```
{extends file='layout.tpl'}

{block name='content'}
    {block name='menu'}
      <ul>
          <li>Link 1</li>
          <li>Link 2</li>
          <li>Link 3</li>
      </ul>
    {/block}
    {block name='actualContent'}{/block}
{/block}
```

**page.tpl**

```
{extends file='default.tpl'}

{block name='menu'}
    <div class="first-page-example">
        {$smarty.block.parent}
    </div>
{/block}
{block name='actualContent'}
    <span>I'm text only for first page....</span>
{/block}
```

I don't know much about the background of your project but personally I would not add too much structure to `page.tpl`. So my alternate would look like so

**layout.tpl**

```
<div class='layout'>
  {block name='content'}{/block}
</div>
```

**default.tpl**

```
{extends file='layout.tpl'}
{block 'content'}
    <header>
        <nav>
        {block 'menu'}
            <ul>
                <li>Link 1</li>
                <li>Link 2</li>
                <li>Link 3</li>
            </ul>
        {/block}
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        {block 'actualContent'}comming soon...{/block}
    </main>
{/block}
```

**page.tpl**

```
{extends file='default.tpl'}
{block 'actualContent'}
    <article>I'm text only for first page....</article>
{/block}
```

This doesnt exactly answers your question but may help I think.

Comment: Thanks, it's really works. But i'm a little incorrectly explain what i trying to get, cause i have 3 files `layout.tpl default.tpl page.tpl`. I edited my question, can you please check it?

Comment: Yeap, it works, but not really what i'm trying to get. In that case you cant directly set in which place block `menu` from `default.tpl` will be added in `page.tpl`. For example if you will try add `menu` to child (`page.tpl`) between text `only` and `for`, you couldnt to do that. :[

Comment: If the placement of menu isnt fix and you dont really need to overwrite its content, `include` could be a better choice here.

Comment: Indeed include it's not so bad solution to solve that problem. Many thanks for your help, **sofl** :)